# How do I link people back to the mobile site from the full site?

Tags: mobile, mobile-web

I have a full site and the mobile site is set to launch pretty soon.

I am autodetecting if the user is on a mobile and redirecting them to the mobile site automatically. I will have a link in the footer as standard practice which says "Full Site".

The question is - On the full site, there is no link to get back to the mobile site. 
What are the best practices? Do you guys know of good examples?

Comment: @Sylar's answer is good -- I would only add that you should give the user the option of viewing the full site on their mobile device.  Particularly if your mobile version does not offer 100% of the content included in the full site.

Comment: And please PLEASE make sure that when you redirect, you go to the same page that they were on. It's very frustrating when someone sends you a deep link to a site, you open it on your phone, and you get redirected to the mobile 'front page'.

Comment: Don't force me to the mobile site just because I happen to be using a mobile device! Let me go to the normal site. Maybe show a hint that there is a mobile version, but do not assume that you know better than I do where I want to go.

Comment: @MarjanVenema well if you have both a mobile and a desktop site you have to make a decision which version you're going to serve up to whom. You *have* to assume one or the other. Working on the assumption that 'if you're on mobile, and we have a mobile site then we'll give you that one' isn't really a wild assumption to make.

Comment: @JonW: If the two sites have different addresses, ie m.mydomain.com for the mobile site and www.mydomain.com for the browser site, you should respect the address I typed in, regardless of the device I use. Especially when the sites have differences in functionality. Some mobile sites do not offer "preferences" or whatever, while the main site does, and then force a redirect on me when I am on my mobile regardless of the fact that I typed in the main site's address in my phone's web browser, making it impossible to change my ... when on mobile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a good idea to have a link back to mobile site on the full site. Its a good practice. Sometimes the auto-direct doesn't work, and hence this might come in practice.

Here is a good read - [mobile site Vs full site](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-site-vs-full-site/)

The third point here states that you should have a link back.

As for an example, ope up gmail from your mobile browser, they have a link to the full site. And when you are on the full site, they have a button called "standard" instead of full site on the bottom which redirects back to the mobile version. So its a pretty good practice and gmail does it. (though I disagree with using standard as the button name, it should simply say "Mobile".

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind how your desktop site will look on mobile devices. **Making your mobile link large enough for mobile may make it rather obtrusive on desktop.** Tucking it out of the way in the footer is a reasonable solution.

Another device that I've found helpful in getting those mobile visitors to the redirect link is **showing them a device icon**. It's just a cue to let them know what the link will do, even if they can't read the link text when scaled on the phone.